# Получить сформированный html код страницы со стилями?

Tags: javascript, html

Каким образом можно получить html код страницы со всеми примененными стилями?
То есть нужна строка html кода.

Comment: Вот такая мысль: начиная с `body`, проходите по всем элементам. В цикле определяете все стили с помощью `getComputedStyle`, все эти стили записываете в атрибут соответствующего элемента,в итоге получаем искомую  строку в `document.documentElement.innerHTML`

Comment: а что в варианте
`document.getElementsByTagName("html")` вас не устаревает ?

Comment: Когда делаю так, то возникает исключение

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'height' of object '#<SVGSVGElement>'

Comment: Как "так" Вы делаете?